# Отправить массив ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

В форме 3 одинаковых input

```
<form method="POST" id="formx" action="javascript:void(null);" onsubmit="send()">
   <input id="name" name="name" value="" type="text">
   <input id="text" name="text" value="" type="text">
      <div class="input-holder">
          <input id="pole" type="text" name="rol">
          <input id="pole" type="text" name="rol">
          <input id="pole" type="text" name="rol">
      </div>
    <input value="Отправить" type="submit"> 
</form>
```

Отправляю форму через ajax

```
function send() {
  var msg   = $('#formx').serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'send.php',
      data: msg,  
        success: function(data) {
            $('#results').html(data);
         },
      error:  function(xhr, str){
    alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
      }
    });

}
```

Отправляется корректно, send.php принимает файл но параметр role последний введеный, как упаковать в массив все 3 шт `<input id="pole" type="text" name="rol">` и предать массивом через ajax ?

Comment: `<input id="pole" type="text" name="rol[]">`

Comment: Благодарю !!!!!

Comment: @Федотов, идентификаторы не могут повторяться. Это семантическая ошибка. Сделайте так, чтобы у ваших инпутов не повторялись id.

Comment: Ответ от Alpha правильный, все работает с одинаковыми id, создается массив

Comment: Федотов, при этом у вас дальнейшие скрипты будут спотыкаться и будут проблемы со взаимодействием элементов. Если надо использовать идентификатор много раз, замените его на класс. Есть стандарты - id для одного элемента, class - для множества. Иначе через неделю вы приедете сюда с массивным кодом и вопросом а-ля "почему отрисовывает лишний инпут и откуда он взялся"

Comment: @Федотов, или наоборот, у вас будет несколько объектов с одним и тем же id, вы используете где-нибудь getElementByID("pole"), рассчитывая, что выберутся и обработаются скопом все такие объекты, а на самом деле будет найден первый такой элемент, а остальные будут проигнорированы. Здесь лучше использовать даже не классы, а атрибут "data-...". В вашем случае data-id="pole" вполне подойдёт.